# How to print directly without showing print dialog using python script in windows?

Tags: python, windows, printing

I've created a desktop application to print a token from a printer, using **python2.7** and **gtk+3** in **Windows** OS. A button in my application should invoke a print from the file. For formatting the print I've used a **.rtf** file, opens the corresponding text editor (in my case MS Word) before printing the file out of the printer and then immediately closes.

How I can avoid it opening and closing before it prints? Whether it's with MS Word settings, Windows or a solution in Python.

Here's my code:

```
def make_print(self):
    os.startfile("print.rtf", "print")
```

Note "**print.rtf**" is created by a python script prior to this call.

I also tried this, but it isn't even printing.

```
def make_print1(self):
    with open('print.rtf', 'r') as f, open('LPT1:', 'w') as lpt:
        while True:
            buf = f.read()
            if not buf: break
            lpt.write(buf)
```

Comment: I am not sure if I well understood your problem, but why you don't just use a `time.sleep()`?

Comment: What do you mean by printing? Creating an rtf file? Or do you want a physical printer to put this text on a page?

Comment: @WajdiFarhani: it is getting printed when calling make_print() method. But the problem is, a dialog box like screen is opening up and closing it automatically in a flash before it print. The screen is probably MS Word application print dialog. My problem is how to do not show this opening up and closing that dialog box.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: I need a physical page to print from the printer. Fortunately I could see the print is coming from the printer. Before that print action a dialog box is opening and closing before it print from the printer

Comment: The problem is that the printer isn't capable of deciphering a file by itself, it needs an application that can convert the file to printer commands through the driver. If you have a printer that understands Postscript you may be able to send it a `ps` file directly, but not `rtf`.

Comment: I'd suggest calling the printer's .dll directly with ctypes, but without the API used, that's not a very useful suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom, let me try that way. Between, whether formatting the print file is possible in your way ?

Comment: Postscript is all about formatting, so you can certainly generate a formatted file but it might not be easy. As a test you should try to convert one of your existing files from `rtf` to `ps` using some application, then send it to the printer as you tried in your second method.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thank you, now I'm more clear in your solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution is works only in windows. for this you need to install [pywin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) [http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html] module.

Instead of creating rtf or ps, we can just send it directly to the printer using DC (Device context).

here is the solution that I have tried.

```
import win32print, win32ui, win32gui
import win32con, pywintypes

# create a dc (Device Context) object (actually a PyCDC)
dc = win32ui.CreateDC()

# convert the dc into a "printer dc"

# get default printer
printername = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter ()
# leave out the printername to get the default printer automatically
dc.CreatePrinterDC(printername)

# you need to set the map mode mainly so you know how
# to scale your output.  I do everything in points, so setting
# the map mode as "twips" works for me.
dc.SetMapMode(win32con.MM_TWIPS) # 1440 per inch

# here's that scaling I mentioned:
scale_factor = 20 # i.e. 20 twips to the point

# start the document.  the description variable is a string
# which will appear in the print queue to identify the job.
dc.StartDoc('Win32print test')

# to draw anything (other than text) you need a pen.
# the variables are pen style, pen width and pen color.
pen = win32ui.CreatePen(0, int(scale_factor), 0)

# SelectObject is used to apply a pen or font object to a dc.
dc.SelectObject(pen)

# how about a font?  Lucida Console 10 point.
# I'm unsure how to tell if this failed.
font = win32ui.CreateFont({
    "name": "Lucida Console",
    "height": int(scale_factor * 10),
    "weight": 400,
})

# again with the SelectObject call.
dc.SelectObject(font)

# okay, now let's print something.
# TextOut takes x, y, and text values.
# the map mode determines whether y increases in an
# upward or downward direction; in MM_TWIPS mode, it
# advances up, so negative numbers are required to
# go down the page.  If anyone knows why this is a
# "good idea" please email me; as far as I'm concerned
# it's garbage.
dc.TextOut(scale_factor * 72,
    -1 * scale_factor * 72,
    "Testing...")

# for completeness, I'll draw a line.
# from x = 1", y = 1"
dc.MoveTo((scale_factor * 72, scale_factor * -72))
# to x = 6", y = 3"
dc.LineTo((scale_factor * 6 * 72, scale_factor * 3 * -72))

# must not forget to tell Windows we're done.
dc.EndDoc()
```

Tested on windows8.1 / python 3.4

Reference : http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/pythonicwindowsprinting.html